# Is there any c# api available ,which executes any script files or executables?

Tags: c#

I am looking for c# program which can execute any script (VB. script,powershell script etc) or executable files, if file path is  provided to the program.if any api available, then plz tell me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("yourprogrampath");
```

Comment: Thank you Very much. i know about Process.Start() before, but didnt know we can execute files also by using this.

Comment: In case of Powershell script,will it work?

Comment: If it's a `.ps1` file then it should, just think of `Process.Start` as double clicking on the file you want to run.